# Validate textbox when radio button is checked yes using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to show hide the texboxes and validate textbox when radio button is checked "Yes". When radio button is checked "No" error message should not be displayed. Show/hide works fine for me but validating the texboxes doesnt work for me.It displays error message when radio button is checked no and textbox is hidden.I am new to jquery Please help me. Here is the code.

```
      $(function() {

      $("input[name='chkPassPort']").click(function () {
            if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked")) {
                $("#dvPassport").show();
            } else {
                $("#dvPassport").hide();
            }
        });


        $("#XISubmit").click(function(){
  var project1=document.forms["XIForm"]["project1"].value;
            var funding1=document.forms["XIForm"]["funding1"].value;
if(  project1==null || project1=="") {alert("Please enter Project title"); return false;}
    if(funding1==null || funding1=="") {alert("Please enter Funding Agency"); return false;}
document.getElementById("XIForm").submit();

            }); 

    }); 

<form name="XIForm" id="XIForm" method="POST" action="" style="margin-bottom:-10px;">
<input type="radio" id="chkYes" name="chkPassPort" value="Yes" />
    Yes
</label>
<label for="chkNo">
    <input type="radio" id="chkNo" name="chkPassPort" value="No"/>
    No
</label>
<div id="dvPassport" style="display: none">
        <table cellpadding="10px">
        <tr>
    <td style="width:250px">Project Title</td>
    <td style="width:250px">Funding agency</td>

    </tr>
    <br/>
    <tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="project1" id="project1"  style="width: 220px;border:solid 1px #0096ce;margin-right:40px;padding: 5px 3px; " maxlength="80"/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="funding1" id="funding1"  style="width: 220px;border:solid 1px #0096ce;padding: 5px 3px;margin-right:28px; " maxlength="80"/></td>


        </tr>
</table></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      if ($("#chkYes").is(":checked"))
         {
           if(  project1==null || project1=="") {alert("Please enter Project title"); return false;}
           if(funding1==null || funding1=="") {alert("Please enter Funding Agency"); return false;}
          document.getElementById("XIForm").submit();
           }
```

Check radio button before submit.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

By following method you can check values

```
        var project1= $("#<%= project1.ClientID %>").val();
                        if(project1== "")
                        {
                        alert("Please enter a name");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Welcome: "+name);
                        }

        var funding1= $("#<%= funding1.ClientID %>").val();
                        if(funding1== "")
                        {
                        alert("Please enter a name");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Welcome: "+name);
                        }
```

and if you want to validate with respect of hide and show text boxes individually then you can get this validations in a function and call the specific function

Example:

```
      function CheckProject1Text1()
      {
       var project1= $("#<%= project1.ClientID %>").val();
                        if(project1== "")
                        {
                        alert("Please enter a name");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Welcome: "+name);
                        }
    }
    function CheckFunding1Text1()
    {
     var funding1= $("#<%= funding1.ClientID %>").val();
                        if(funding1== "")
                        {
                        alert("Please enter a name");
                        }
                        else{
                            alert("Welcome: "+name);
                        }
    }
```